# Reporting Services - Excel column with number format

Tags: sql, excel, datetime, reporting

I am using the following function to format a calculation in Reporting Services 2012:

```
=Format(DateAdd("s", (DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, Fields!FechaInicio.Value, Fields!FechaFinal.Value)), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")
```

When I export the file to Excel it shows me the column with the General data type. Is there a way for the column to be exported with the Numeric data type?

Comment: Please remove the wrong tags like tsql. Your question has nothing to do wish tsql and you should not "cheat" the reader in order to make more people read your question. Use the right tags to get the best experts relevant question.

Comment: It is not my intention to "cheat" anyone. I added that category because it is related to SQL. I just corrected it

Comment: I did not meant that you want to cheat us but that it might do it (maybe a better word is "mislead by mistake" and not cheat. Anyway, I see that you removed the un-related tag `:-)` . Well done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options; Cast and Convert. See the code below and adapt to your needs

```
--Drop Table t

SELECT *
INTO t
FROM (VALUES
   (45, 'alex'),
   (98, 'diana'),
   (32, 'peter'),
   (98, 'daniel'),
   (45, 'alex'),
   (23, 'bob'),
   (98, 'peter')
   )
v (id, name)


Select * 
From t


SELECT CAST(id AS INT) FROM t;
GO
SELECT CONVERT(INT,id) FROM t;
GO
```

Here is a link for more info.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15